# Explain how to find derivatives using Taylor/Maclaurin polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I understand the concept behind this process, but I just don't understand how to do it in practice. Can someone briefly walk me through a generic example?

Comment: You can also find maximum or minimum by application of Taylor series...You may google it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Taylor approximation of a polynomial is the method of approximation of a function not is the *form of a polynomial* in the form of a polynomial ie. in the form-$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x^1+a_0x^0$.

The Taylor expansion (speaking the truth the formula I am writhing below is the McLaurin series which is a special case of Taylor Series) of a polynomial is given by-$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$ where $f^{(n)}(0)$ represents the n-th derivative of the function at the functional value $f(0)$.

Using this definition,$\sin x$ can be approximated as $$\sin x=f(0)+\frac{f^{(1)}(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!}x^2+...=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$$

Hope this helps you to get a basic idea!!